# Merge paneldata with cross-section data

Tags: r, merge, panel

I'm trying to merge a longitudinal datase with a cross-section data set containing two variables. IDs can be used to merge.

My two dataframes looks something like this:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2) 
var2 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
df1 <- c(id, var1, var2)
```

and

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
age <- c(22, 24, 26, 58, 60, 62, 35, 37, 39)
xvar <- c(5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1)

df2 <- c(id, age, xvar)
```

I've used the following code to combine the two dataframes:

```
the_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id)
```

However all it does is just adding af new row with NA's in all variables from df1, and only values in df2 like this:

```
|id|age|xvar|var1|var2|
|--|---|----|----|----|
| 1| 22| 5  |NA  |NA  |
| 1| 24| 5  |NA  |NA  |
| 1| 26| 5  |NA  |NA  |
| 1| NA| NA |1   | 1  |
| 2| 58| 7  |NA  |NA  |
| 2| 60| 7  |NA  |NA  |
| 2| 62| 7  |NA  |NA  |
| 2| NA| NA |2   |1   |
```

Instead i just want the values from df2 to follow the id in the paneldata, and not add another id-row. The result should be like this:

```
|id|age|xvar|var1|var2|
|--|---|----|----|----|
| 1| 22| 5  |1   |1   |
| 1| 24| 5  |1   |1   |
| 1| 26| 5  |1   |1   |
| 2| 58| 6  |2   |1   |
| 2| 60| 6  |2   |1   |
| 2| 62| 6  |2   |1   |
```

Hoping anyone can help me here! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `merge()` or `dplyr::left_join()`, not `bind_rows()` or `rbind()`.

Also in creating your data frame you should use `data.frame()` or `tibble()`, not `c()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2) 
var2 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
df1 <- data.frame(id, var1, var2)

id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
age <- c(22, 24, 26, 58, 60, 62, 35, 37, 39)
xvar <- c(5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1)

df2 <- data.frame(id, age, xvar)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "id")
#>   id age xvar var1 var2
#> 1  1  22    5    1    2
#> 2  1  24    5    1    2
#> 3  1  26    5    1    2
#> 4  2  58    7    2    2
#> 5  2  60    7    2    2
#> 6  2  62    7    2    2
#> 7  3  35    1    1    1
#> 8  3  37    1    1    1
#> 9  3  39    1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `merge`

```
> merge(df1, df2, all.y = TRUE)
  id var1 var2 age xvar
1  1    1    2  22    5
2  1    1    2  24    5
3  1    1    2  26    5
4  2    2    2  58    7
5  2    2    2  60    7
6  2    2    2  62    7
7  3    1    1  35    1
8  3    1    1  37    1
9  3    1    1  39    1
```